# Force subscribers to re-request data from Service?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-services, angular-components

I have a simple structure, with multiple components and a single service [[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wh5noo)]:

[image: <code>digraph G { s[label="Service"]; c0[label="Component0"]; c1[label="Component1"]; c2[label="Component2"]; c0->c1; c0->c2; c1->s; c2->s; }</code>]

### Service

```typescript
@Injectable()
export class Service {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  post(entity: IEntity): Observable<IEntity> {
    return this.http
               .post<IEntity>('/api/entity', entity)
               .pipe(map(parseDates));
  }

  get(): Observable<IEntity[]> {
    return this.http
               .get<IEntity[]>('/api/entity')
               .pipe(map(parseDates));
  }
}
```

### Component0

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component0',
  template: `<app-component1></app-component1>
             <app-component2></app-component2>`,
  styleUrls: []
})
export class Component0 {}
```

### Component1

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component1-create',
  template: `<button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>`,
  styleUrls: []
})
export class Component1 {    
    constructor(private service: Service) { }

    submit() {
        this.service.post({foo: 'bar'})
                    .subscribe(console.info, console.error)
    }
}
```

### Component2

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component2-table',
  template: `<pre>{{ entities | json }}</pre>`,
  styleUrls: []
})
export class Component2 implements OnInit {
    entities: IEntity[];

    constructor(private service: Service) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.get()
                    .subscribe(entities => this.entities = entities,
                               console.error)
    }
}
```

---

How do I get `Component1` to update `Component2`, through the `Service`?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: You want that, whenever you submit on `comp1` (that is to say send a `post` request to database which is unrelated to the `entities` property of `comp2`) it should update `entities` on `comp2`, is that correct?

Comment: Just added a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wh5noo) link. Yes that's correct. It could be that I'm not meant to have an `entities` property of `comp2`, it could be that I store something in the service instead, it could be that I use `BehaviourSubject` or `Subject` instead of a loose array. How do I handle this common scenario, in a maintainable way?

Answer (score 1):

you should have another observable to mitigate your component communication :

```
@Injectable()
export class StoreService {

  private _employes$ = new BehaviorSubject<{id:number,employee_name:string,employee_salary:number,employee_age:number}[]>([]);

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    this.refresh();
  }

  refresh() {
    this._http.get<{id:number,employee_name:string,employee_salary:number,employee_age:number}[]>('https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees').subscribe(
      data => this._employes$.next(data)
    );
  }

  post() {
      const payload = {"name":"test","salary":"123","age":"23"};

      this._http.post('https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/create', payload).subscribe(() => {
        this.refresh();
      })
  }

  get employes$(): Observable<{id:number,employee_name:string,employee_salary:number,employee_age:number}[]> {
    return this._employes$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Which are compose by two part :

Observable use by your store, when you want to update your stream, you can next to it.

```
private _employes$ = new BehaviorSubject<{...}[]>([]);
```

Exposed getter. Any component which need to be inform by any change on your store can subscribe to it.

```
  get employes$(): Observable<{...}[]> {
    return this._employes$.asObservable();
  }
```

---

From now all is relative to your actual case, you have various way to update this internal observable :

**the quickest way :**

```
refresh() {
    this._http.get<{...}[]>('...').subscribe(
      data => this._employes$.next(data)
    );
  }
```

Inside your service, you subscribe to your http call and update your internal observable.

**Pro :**

- you don't expose the request.
- Very easy to maintain as only one place can make API call.

**Con :**

- Is not adapted to some case where you want to actually control, update, ... do something specific with the API answer.
- Is not always good idea to subscribe on service.

---

**Observable gymnastic**

If you don't want to subscribe on your service. You can do something like :

```
return this._http.get<{...}[]>('...')
    .pipe(switchMap(result => {
        this._employes$.next(result);
        return this.employes$;
    }));
```

you transform your http get observable to the internal observable. At the same time you next the new result of your API answer.

If tomorrow you need to delegate a special traitment on the API response before make it available accross your application.

you can do :

```
refresh(myCustomTraitment: = null) {
    return this._http.get<{...}[]>('...')
        .pipe(switchMap(result => {
            if (myCustomTraitment) {
                result = result.map(myCustomTraitment);
            }
            this._employes$.next(result);
            return this._employes$;
        }));
}
```

---

[Online sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sw1c7i)